# How to get the text of a h1 headline with playwright?

Tags: playwright

I want to test if a headline has a certain text. Is there a command for this?

```
await page.goto(‘<http://localhost:3000/>');


expect(await page.$("data-testid=headline")).toBe("my headline")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`page.$()` only returns: `<Promise<null|ElementHandle>>`

You should use `innerText` or `innerHtml` like this:

```
expect(await page.innerText("data-testid=headline")).toBe("my headline")

expect(await page.innerHtml("data-testid=headline")).toBe("my headline")
```

These two methods will return `<Promise<string>>`

`innerText` only return the text, while `innerHtml` will return all things inside it. For example:

```
<p>
  <a>Hey</a>
  Helloworld!
</p>
```

`page.innerText("p")` will return `Helloworld!`.

But `page.innerHtml("p")` will return `<a>Hey</a>Helloworld!`

Hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using page.locator with CSS selector seems to be the CSS like approach to query for an element reference.

```
const elm = page.locator('h1.header');
```

as an example.

https://playwright.dev/docs/1.18/selectors#text-selector